# Deja: Save backup at more places

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I want make a backup with deja and save this backup local and about ssh for example.
Is it possible to choose two or more places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deja-dup intentionally is designed to be very simple, allowing the user to create a reliable backup without hiss. It therefore does not, [and will not](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/324631), feature an option to have multiple destinations.

You may use the command line tool duplicity to do backups in different locations. Duplicity is the backend used by Deja-dup, and accordingly makes a similar type of backups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So are the backups also backwards compatible?

Comment: Not sure, but likely yes: duplicity works with standard proven command line tools. These do not tend to change quickly in a fundamental way.